# Multivariable Maclaurin Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Find Maclaurin series for

**a)** $\cos(x + y)$

**b)** $\frac{\log(1 + x)}{(1 + y)}$.

Honestly, I'm really just confused about the process of finding a Taylor series expansion for multivariate equation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

$$f(x,y)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\sum^k_{i=0} \frac{(x-a)^{k-i}(y-b)^i}{(k-i)!i!} \left[\frac{\partial^kf}{\partial x^{k-i} \partial y^i}\right]_{(a=0,b=0)}$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
Consider the general formula, try relating it to single variable formula of Taylor's series.

$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)$ 
$$+\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}(x-x_0)+\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y}(y-y_0)\quad \Rightarrow Order 1$$$
$$+\frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x^2}(x-x_0)^2+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y^2}(y-y_0)^2+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x\partial y}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)\bigg) \quad \Rightarrow Order 2$

And repeat this for higher orders.

For Maclaurin's the formula is much more simpler as $x_0=y_0=0$

Do you still have a problem evaluating the thing? Tell me where you're struck.

Comment: In the 2nd order why $$+\frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x^2}(x-x_0)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y^2}(y-y_0)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x\partial y}(x-x_0)(y-y_0)\bigg) \quad \Rightarrow Order 2$$ instead of $$+\frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x^2}(x-x_0)^2+\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial y^2}(y-y_0)^2\bigg) +\frac{\partial^2 f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x\partial y}(x-x_0)(y-y_0) \quad \Rightarrow Order 2$$?

Comment: @KYHSGeekCode indeed in order two there should be a 2! there in all order 2 terms..